# WiringPi, PHP: Interrupt driven event counter

Tags: php, wiringpi, html5

I am planning to set up an HTML-PHP website gui which opens up in Chromium Kiosk mode.

I want the gui to count the number of falling edge interrupts and show the count on the GUI.

I have achieved this functionality quite easily using a C-program, but I don't know how to update the count php-variable on the GUI website.

The wiringPi GPIO utility does provide some functionality regarding GPIO pins, but not related to interrupts. This is the [tutorial](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/07/PHP-on-Raspberry-Pi) regarding wiringPi/PHP.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to be using Python, why use WiringPi? You can read the GPIO pins directly from Python in many cases.
http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-and-writing-from-gpio-ports-from-python/

Comment: I am not using Python at all. But can switch to Python as well. But, the problem still stands, how can I update the HTML webpage GUI through python application running at the back?

Comment: For somethings (thermocouples, for sure) the values are written to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at [phpi-websocket](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi-websocket), it has everything you need to implement what you're after, so it'd just be a matter of looking at the examples and trimming out what you don't need.

It uses a native PHP library to interact with the edge detection registers and does an event-based push to an HTML page via websockets.

As mentioned before, there's more than you need in the example - you're mainly interested in this part on the server:

```
$pin->on(\Calcinai\PHPi\Pin::EVENT_LEVEL_CHANGE, function() use($pin, $controller){
    $controller->broadcast('pin.level', ['pin' => $pin->getPinNumber(), 'level' => $pin->getLevel()]);
});
```

which handles the pin change event and broadcasts it. Then on the client

```
.bind('pin.level', function(data){
    $('.pin[data-bcm="'+data.pin+'"]').data('level', data.level);
})
```

which binds that javascript event to the UI.  You can easily make it do something like increment a variable instead.

*disclaimer: I'm the author and maintainer of the above library*